# RequestCode changes along the way

Tags: android-fragments, android-camera-intent

I have a fragment within a fragment

both fragments load fine, except in one of the fragments i have a start camera intent with activity for result

```
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQ_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
```

now my REQ_TAKE_PHOTO is defined as follows :

```
public static final int REQ_TAKE_PHOTO=301;
```

however, in my onActivityResult the request code i get when returning from the camera intent is
**131373** -> not the code i sent the request with

**what could be changing the code along the way ?**

note that when the inner fragment (the one that is incharge of taking the picture) is run separately, the code returns as 301 normally

Comment: Do you have the code 131373 anywhere else in your app?

Comment: no i do not. and this text is added to make the post longer even though it is no needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make the `requestCode` be what it was when i started the startActivityForResult

I need to do `requestCode&0xffff`

This is apparently a bug in the android support library
according to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15394